# How to run a VSCode project in the background via Jenkins?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, jenkins, vscode-debugger

I need to launch my project, after which the server is activated locally, with which I will already work further. I'm trying to automate it. I'm doing a launch via Jenkins.

On my computer, I run the command

```
code --extensionDevelopmentPath=Path
```

After that, VSCode opens and my scripts run.
By executing the same command in Jenkins

```
script {
    stage('browser') {
        sh "pwd"
        dir('./path_main') {
            sh "pwd"
            sh "code --extensionDevelopmentPath=Path"
            sh "sleep 60"
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing happens. Is it possible to launch the project through Jenkins?

Comment: Why do you need to run whatever you need to run _via VS Code_? VS Code has no concept of projects, it's just an IDE. What type of "scripts" are these? Can't you just run the scripts _directly from Jenkins_? For example, if it's a shell script or a Python script, you can just run those directly from Jenkins. I doubt you need VS Code's GUI to be run/displayed as part of your Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: @GinoMempin My project consists of a large number of files, so I can't just rewrite it to Jenkins for execution. But I also can't run this project, for example, using `node path` because I get the error `Error: Cannot find module 'vscode'` which I can't fix yet

Comment: I wasn't suggesting copying or rewriting them in Jenkins. I was suggesting running or executing them _directly from Jenkins_, skipping VS Code entirely. There is no description on this question on what these scripts are, but if you can execute them from VS Code (via the terminal or via a build task or a launch task), then you should be able to execute them _directly_ too, indepedently of VS Code. You mentioned `node`, and [Jenkins even has plugins specific for NodeJS scripts](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodejs/). My main confusion is why VS Code is needed _at all_ to run these scripts.

Comment: First try to figure out how to run it on your local machine apart from using the command that you mentioned.  you could write a script that will load everything into that so that you have one launch script to run it. Once you figure this out then running it from jenkins is straightforward